# OBJLoader with OrbitControls rotating issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have loaded a OBJ model using the three.js OBJLoader to which I have also added OrbitControls. Whenever I add a value on the object's x position the controls changes its axis which it rotates around. Without the x value it works properly. How would I go about fixing this issue?
Not working:

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( 'obj/cylinder/' );
                objLoader.load( 'body_dyn.obj', function ( object ) {

                    object.position.y =- 100;
                    object.position.x =- 100;
                    scene.add( object );

                }, onProgress, onError );
```

Working:

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( 'obj/cylinder/' );
                objLoader.load( 'body_dyn.obj', function ( object ) {

                    object.position.y =- 100;

                    scene.add( object );

                }, onProgress, onError );
```

Comment: how do you create an instance of OrbitControls?

Comment: the controls start rotating around a different axis? This sounds rather impossible.